# Does a man's ejaculation of semen decrease in volume, with age?

Tags: ejaculation

My question is:  As I get older, should I expect that the volume of my semen will decrease?

Comment: The porn elements of your question were unnecessary, so I edited them out. If you disagree, you can revert my edits.

Answer (score 4):

First off, not sure if this question is serious or not, but here goes.

According to [this study](https://academic.oup.com/humrep/article/18/2/447/639258) (n=97, age 22-80):

> After adjusting for covariates, semen volume decreased by 0.03 ml per
>   year of age

I have no idea how much volume is in a handful of semen, but

> The median semen volume was 2.7 ml

The average age in the population was 46.

Therefore, we can expect that on average, if the average volume of ejaculate in a 46 year old is 2.7 mL, the average volume of a 20 year old would be 3.46 mL, and the average volume of an 85 year old would be 1.53 mL. **This gives a net ejaculation volume loss between ages 20 and 85 of 1.93 mL, or 55%.**

HUGE caveat(s):

- This was a relatively small study using a convenience sample
- None of the participants were as young as 20 or as old as 85
- There is no data to say whether the decline is an absolute or relative, ie does everyone lose 0.03 a year, or is it a fixed percentage.
- Peter North is a clear outlier and so it's impossible to say how this data applies to him
- "Handful" is not an accepted unit of measurement for semen volume
- The study did not address the question of elderly ejaculate feeling like sand